# Quantidade de marcadores no Google Maps

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps

Estava estudando algumas formas de implementar o Google Maps, e vi em um [site do WordPress](http://wp-brasil.org/) um mapa com a contagem das informações, eu queria saber se vocês conhecem um plug-in que faça o mesmo, ou através da documentação que o Google oferece para desenvolvedores, como implanta-lo. Gostaria de aprender mais sobre isso.

Comment: É possível fazer um efeito parecido seguindo os passos citados nesse [link](http://www.princiweb.com.br/blog/programacao/google-apis/google-maps-api-v3-criando-um-mapa-personalizado.html).

Comment: @Emanoel se quiseres dar uma resposta explicando esse link e trazendo exempo de como implementar o plugin seria uma resposta interessante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um tempo depois de fazer essa pergunta, achei a resposta por acaso (pois eu tinha parado de pesquisar), vi um rapaz falando sobre alguns recursos essenciais, entre os recursos estava lá! MARKPLACES <3 ...
Foi amor ao primeiro clique, e descobri uma documentação bem completa do Google!

> #### ["Too Many Markers!"](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers?utm_source=welovemapsdevelopers&utm_campaign=mdr-screencasts)
>
> Some applications are required to display a large number of locations or markers. Naively plotting thousands of markers on a map can quickly lead to a degraded user experience. Too many markers on the map cause both visual overload and sluggish interaction with the map. To overcome this poor performance, the information displayed on the map needs to be simplified.

Tudo o que eu queria saber em relação ao agrupamento de marks está ali, muito bom e recomendo!
Fazer um plug-in para o WordPress com essa documentação ficou mais fácil!

Comment: Muito boa referência, mais tarde vou incluir na wiki da tag google-maps. Marcada como favorita!

Comment: @brasofilo Obrigado!